# Deploying Cloud Run via YAML gives Revision named 'yourservicename-00001-soj' with different configuration already exists

Tags: google-cloud-run

When using the following command to deploy a new Cloud Run revision,

```
gcloud run services replace service.yaml
```

The deployment fails with this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.replace) ALREADY_EXISTS: Revision named 'yourservicename-00001-soj' with different configuration already exists.
```

This occurs when you have followed Google's documentation which instructs you to pull down the current service YAML description into a file, make edits and then redeploy it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the documentation is wrong, or Google's service has regressed since it was authored.

Edit the YAML and remove `spec.template.metadata.name` and try again.